# Android - affecting a GUI component inside a broadcast receiver

Tags: android, user-interface, broadcastreceiver

What are my options to affect a component inside a broadcast receiver?

When the user taps a button, I generate a process and wait for a broadcast receiver to catch the result. Once this happens, I want the button to change its caption. How can I do this besides defining a global variable that holds the button component and use that inside the broadcast receiver? I wonder if there's a cleaner/smarter way to do this.

Comment: Have you tried to attach listener to BroadcastReceiver which will be implemented in Activity class and which will update the GUI?

Comment: Nope, Actually I have no idea how to do so

Answer (score 2):

Use an event bus (`LocalBroadcastManager`, Square's Otto, greenrobot's EventBus). Have your `BroadcastReceiver` post a message to the bus. Have your UI layer subscribe to the bus when it is relevant (e.g., when the activity/fragment is in the foreground). Your UI layer will then be notified about the subscribed-to message from the bus, and it can update its UI.

Comment: Do you have it in Chinese? :) I'm sorry but I'm not that expert to know how to implement what you just wrote

Comment: @Amos: [This directory](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus) contains sample projects from [my book](https://commonsware.com/Android) demonstrating the use of all three event bus implementations that I mentioned. [`LocalBroadcastManager` is part of the Android Support package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html), and [Otto](https://github.com/square/otto) and [greenrobot's EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) have their own sites.